# Oracle upgrade from 12c to 19c - older application no longer works

Tags: oracle

Using an older SQL reporting tool that used oci.dll to interact with Oracle 12c.  Upgrade to Oracle 19c and the tool no longer works.  Is the instant client for 19c the solution or must we revert to ODBC for access?

Thanks for any insights...

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry. Though, I hope you found that out during testing phase of the upgrade, not in production.

Comment: What does "no longer works" mean?

Comment: We can't say what the solution might be if we don't know what the problem is.  " no longer works" is not found in any error reference I know of.

Comment: People want details!  The product communicated to Oracle via oci.dll.  Worked fine until Oracle was updated to 19c.  Upon analyzing, I think they did not download the Instant Client for 19c which contains oci.dll.  I'm trying that today.  But, does anyone know if the oci.dll in 19c is backwards compatible with the one in 12c?

Comment: @Brwells If you can provide the exact error message or behavior that might help us narrow down the problem and provide an answer. For example, if you're getting the error "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol", the problem could be with the SQLNet parameter `ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT` on the server. But without more details, that's just a wild guess.